# Can calls on UIKit pushViewController:animated: cause eventual stack overflows (or other anomalies)?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, stack-overflow

Can calls on UIKit pushViewController cause eventual stack overflows (or other anomalies)? My app now makes use of the `pushViewController:animated:` to navigate across screens, e.g:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:iLovePoniesScreen animated:YES];
```

Will this eventually create an overflow while navigating to and fro screens? Is this the recommended way of screen navigation in UIKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the recommended ways. Unless you're pushing 100's of controllers you shouldn't get into any trouble. When you go back (popping), the view controller you leave is deallocated, and a new one is created if you go forward again, so there's no build up of view controllers.